# What NN architectures exist for variable length input?

Tags: neural-network

I have a vector-valued function $f(X)$ that depends on initial data with variable length.   To be concrete, consider the input to be a point cloud, $X$ is an unordered tuple of $k$ vectors $x_j \in R^n$, where $k$ is not predetermined. (In my application, $n=4$.) I have samples $y_i = f(X_i)$,  for a collection of $X_i$ of variable length, i.e., $k$ is not the same for each $X_i$, and wish to use some neural network to do regression. It is important for the resulting model that it can accept much larger inputs than those I train the model with.

Examples of input, with $n=1$ for simplicity:
$$ X = (0), \quad X = (1,2), \quad X = (\pi,-2,0), \quad X = (0,1) $$

**Q:** What kind of NN architectures exist for such problems?

**Remark:** Padding is *not* an option here, since $f$ has very special properties, $x_j=0$ for some $j$ is a valid input, genuinely different from not having $x_j$ present in the input.